# implementing infinite loop of changing text with React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, css-animations

I'm trying to build a component that is similar to [typed.js](https://mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/), in the sense that text (from an array) will be looped over indefinitely. Here is what I have so far of this component (using styled components):

```
const cdRotateIn = keyframes`
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  35% {
    transform: rotateX(120deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  65% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(360deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
`

const cdRotateOut = keyframes`
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  35% {
    transform: rotateX(-40deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  65% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
`

const Wrapper = styled.div``

const Headline = styled.h1``

const StaticText = styled.span``

const AnimatedTextContainer = styled.span`
  display: inline-block;
  perspective: 300px;
`

const AnimatedText = styled.b`
  opacity: 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;

  ${ifProp('isVisible', css`
    position: relative;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
    animation: ${cdRotateIn} 1.2s;
  `)}

  ${ifProp('isHidden', css`
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
    animation: ${cdRotateOut} 1.2s;
  `)}
`

const FlipAnimation = ({ words }) => {
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0)
  const animationDelay = 1000

  useEffect(() => {
    let loopInterval = setInterval(() => {
      animateHeadline(words)
    }, animationDelay)
    return () => {
      clearInterval(loopInterval)
    }
  }, [])


  const animateHeadline = (words) => {
    setInterval(() => {
      setNextIndex()
    }, animationDelay);
  }

  const setNextIndex = () => {
    if (currentIndex < words.length - 1) {
      setCurrentIndex(currentIndex + 1)
    } else {
      setCurrentIndex(0)
    }
  }

  const animatedTexts = () => words.map((word, index) =>
    <AnimatedText key={index} isVisible={currentIndex === index} isHidden={currentIndex !== index}>{word}</AnimatedText>
  )

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Headline>
        <StaticText>My favourite food is</StaticText>
        <AnimatedTextContainer>
          {animatedTexts()}
        </AnimatedTextContainer>
      </Headline>
    </Wrapper>
  )
}
FlipAnimation.defaultProps = {
  words: ['bacon', 'eggs', 'sausage']
}
```

The issue that I can see here in the debugging console is that currentIndex does not properly get updated on each run of the loop. I can't understand why this is happening, since this code gets run each second:

```
if (currentIndex < words.length - 1) {
   setCurrentIndex(currentIndex + 1)
} else {
   setCurrentIndex(0)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function closes over the `currentIndex` variable from the very first render. So `currentIndex` is always 0, and `setCurrentIndex(currentIndex + 1)` will always try to set it to 1.

One option to fix this is to make sure you create a new function each time, and set a new timeout using that new function. This way, each new function closes over the most recent value. However, there's a simpler approach: setCurrentIndex allows you to pass a function into it, which will get called with whatever the current value happens to be. You can then calculate the new value based on that:

```
setCurrentIndex(previousVal => {
  if (previousVal < words.length - 1) {
    return previousVal + 1;
  }
  return 0;
});
```

Comment: great answer! currentIndex is working correctly now. Could you elaborate on what's happening here under the hood? As I understand it, react components are closures, but I'm unsure why this means that currentIndex is always 0

Comment: You call setInterval exactly once, and you point it to a function. That function is a closure, which has a const named currentIndex in its scope. The value of that const is 0 and will never change. If the component renders again, you do create new functions which have different values in their scope, but no intervals are started with these functions.